# pointer displacement?

Tags: c++, assembly

I have the following code

```
void PacketEncrypt(Packet* packet, int sizeofpacket)
{
    int* pointer;
    pointer = ((int*)packet+sizeofpacket)-2;
    (int)*pointer = packet->PacketSize^0x1A3C;
    packet->Type += 0x0FFF7;
}
```

Problem is when i debug it compiler set it as:

```
0041585E   8B45 0C          MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]
00415861   8B4D 08          MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
00415864   8D5481 F8        LEA EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+EAX*4-8]
```

But what i really want is:

```
0041585E   8B45 0C          MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+C]
00415861   8B4D 08          MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
00415864   8D5481 F8        LEA EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+EAX-2]
```

I am kind of new into C++, so can you help me on what i am doing wrong, or why the compiler is adding scalar *4? thanks !

Comment: Because `int` has a size of 4 bytes on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` pointer has size of `4 bytes` on your machine and can be shifted only by `4*n` bytes. If you need to move pointer by `2 bytes` cast it to `char`, since `sizeof(char) = 1`

```
char *ptr = (char*)otherPtr;
ptr += 2; //shift by 2 bytes

int *ptr = (int*)otherPtr;
ptr += 2; //shift by 8 bytes. (2 * sizeof(int))
```

**EDIT**

`(short*)pointer = something.` - You can't assign to `rvalue`. I think you meant:

```
pointer = (char*) something
```

Or if you need `short` pointer:

```
short *someOtherPointer = something
```

Comment: Please be sure to checkmark either one of the answers given, as they are both correct. If you need further clarification, leaving a comment is useful for that, too.

Comment: i got the following problem now:

  char* pointer;
  pointer = ((char*)packet+sizeofpacket) -2;
  (short*)pointer = packet->PacketSize^0x1A3C;

it says expression must be a modifiable lvalue. i want to do:

WORD PTR [pointer] = packet->PacketSize^0x1A3C

thanks !

Comment: @user1175832: what is packet->PacketSize ?

Comment: its a short type member of a struct i declared

Comment: i change to short *Pointer but the rvalue returns int:

short *pointer = packet->PacketSize^0x1A3C;

not really used to typecasting yet, how can i make the return value short too?

Comment: @user1175832: you can't. All bitwise operations are performed on the values promoted to int

Comment: lol so i cant force the compiler to make?:

MOV REGISTER, POINTER
MOV WORD PTR [REGISTER], Value^0x1A3C

Comment: @user1175832: I don't assembler. Possibly you should ask another question

Answer (score 4):

C++ does pointer arithmetic using the pointer type. `ptr+2` is 2 *elements*, not two bytes past `ptr`. If `sizeof(*ptr)==4`, those two elements are 8 bytes, and `ptr+2` would therefore point 8 bytes past `ptr`.